# Running gdb servers on server which is not directly accessible

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I frequently use gdbserver to remotely debug my programs. I have come across a unique requirement this time where my knowledge of gdb falls short. I want to debug a process remotely but it is not accessible directly. Lets say there are 3 locations A, B and C. The process I want to debug is in C. I have the tools to debug in A. But C is not accessible via A. It is accessible via B which is accessible via A. So I cannot run gdbserver on C and connect through A. Is there a way I can leverage connectivity between A-B and B-C to debug a process running in C through A

Also I do not have ssh keys saved. I can only login using a password and saving keys is not an option.

Comment: Do you have ssh between A-B and B-C? You can do `ssh B` from machine A, then inside this ssh session do `ssh C` and run gdb in command-line mode. You may also setup TCP tunnel over two ssh to get direct connection from tools to gdbserver

Comment: I can ssh. Can you elaborate how to do what you just said

Comment: Can you give some details about how your tools can connect to gdbserver? Try: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html `(gdb) target remote | ssh -T B ssh -T C gdbserver - hello` or ssh -D/-L to create direct tunnel http://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops

Comment: The tools are some gdb plugins which connect to gdb seamlessly. On a usual occasion I would run gdbserver on one machine and gdb on other with the tools. I'll go through the links you have provided to see if I find my solution which I think I would

Answer (score 2):

I think one valid approach here is to use SSH tunnels as follows:

```
┌───────┐    ┌───────┐    ┌───────┐
│ HOSTA │ ←→ │ HOSTB | ←→ │ HOSTC │
└───────┘    └───────┘    └───────┘
```

```sh
# A terminal on HOSTA where you have access to HOSTB:22
# HOSTB has access to HOSTC:22, but HOSTA does not.
ssh BName@HOSTB                                           \
    -f               `# Run in background               ` \
    -N               `# Do not execute a remote command ` \
    -L60022:HOSTC:22 `# HOSTC in the context of HOSTB   `
# Enter your password for BName@HOSTB

# The above maps HOSTA:60022 through HOSTB to HOSTC:22
# Now HOSTA has SSH access to HOSTC.
# Next, open tunnels to other HOSTC ports we need for gdb
ssh CName@localhost `# localhost seems strange here, but is correct ` \
    -p 60022        `# This is the port we forwarded above          ` \
    -f              `# Run in background                            ` \
    -N              `# Do not execute a remote command              ` \
    -L62345:localhost:2345 `# localhost in the context of HOSTC     `
# Enter your password for CName@HOSTC
```

Now you can access both HOSTC via SSH and a free port which can be used for GDB. Next, start the gdbserver on HOSTC

```sh
# A terminal on HOSTA where you have access to HOSTC via localhost:60022
ssh -p 60022 CName@localhost
# Enter your password for CName@HOSTC
# You are now at a terminal on HOSTC
gdbserver :2345 myAppToDebug # Note that 2345 is the port we opened above
```

The gdbserver is now running on HOSTC listening on port 2345. So now you can connect your debugging tool of choice to `HOSTA:62345` and it should work.